# Test Structure Analysis Documentation

Tags: test-management, test-design, documentation, test-strategy, management

**Detail Information**

Currently I am in the process of building a QA structure, the following points are included and each one is designed for a project.

Since I would like to start with the analysis of the individual projects and the test conditions accordingly, I want to give in my analysis accordingly all documentation and feedback to the existing structures. At the same time offer solutions that improve the current process.

In this inquiry I am particularly interested in how best to create an analysis concept or an analysis test plan. How should the structuring be structured?

What should I pay attention to?

I have created a test strategy documentation in the basic outline, but I still lack a better structuring in the area of analysis,

What would you recommend here?

**initial position**

I have created the following structure for my test plan (project dependent). All points are clearly visible. Since there are already older structures in my project, I have to try to record the individual cross connections on the basis of an analysis.

- 1 Introduction
- 1.1 Scope
- 1.1.1 In Scope
- 1.1.2 Out of Scope
- 1.2 Quality Objective
- 1.3 Roles and Responsibilities
- 2 Test Methodology
- 2.1 Overview
- 2.2 Test Levels
- 2.3 Bug Triage
- 2.4 Suspension Criteria and Resumption Requirements
- 2.5 Test Completeness
- 3 Test Deliverables
- 4 Resource & Environment Needs
- 4.1 Testing Tools
- 4.2 Test Environment

But since the point analysis may not be a separate point in the test plan, it is certainly a legitimate question how I define this analysis of existing processes.

The following analyses are therefore carried out in individual cases

- Current structure
- Current Hardware
- How are the tests structured ?
- Which test types are used?
- How high is the test effort ?
- How many employees are busy with the approvals?

In detail it is therefore a matter of analysing the current structure of the processes.

I had not found an answer at Stackoverflow. Because my problem is not the test strategy, but first and foremost the pure analysis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most used frameworks for testing strategies is [Bach's Heuristic Test Strategy Model](https://www.satisfice.com/download/heuristic-test-strategy-model) (HTSM).

Given that the the main goal testing is to enable us to discover the Perceived Quality of a product, the HTSM starts by investigating the characteristics of the project (Project Env), its quality criteria, and how it is composed (Product Elements).

With this understanding, you can strategize which Test Techniques can be used **in this project** to yield the quality information it requires.

[image]

You can find details of each component in the original (5-page long) paper [here](https://www.satisfice.com/download/heuristic-test-strategy-model).
Also, I have designed a mindmap with the paper information. You can find it [here](http://thatsabug.com/2018/06/18/the-heuristic_testing_strategy_model_mindmap_.html).

Comment: Thank´s @joao that´s realy good!

Comment: Most welcome @Mornon. If you find this answers your question, could you mark it as accepted? It really motivates contributors.

Comment: Hi, Joao,

I marked it as solved accordingly. Unfortunately, this link does not work in your answer, is the mindmap. Possible rights problems? 

http://thatsabug.com/2018/06/18/the-heuristic_testing_strategy_model_mindmap_.html

Comment: Can you access http://thatsabug.com//assets/mindmaps/heuristic_testing_strategy_model.xmind ?

Comment: i can now download the file! Thank´s