# Structuring of a test strategy paper (Review)

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, test-planning, review

The first step is not to create a test plan, but a strategy paper which should provide basic information about the planning of a new concept. 
Since I am here with a customer who needs information for planning as quickly as possible, I have obtained the basic information on the current test system.

- No unit test - customer does not want one ^^
- No RESTAPI test
- Integration tests are under construction
- No Penetration Test and No Load and Performance Test

This question only deals with the structure of a test strategy paper and the question "What exactly should a test strategy paper contain". I see this rather as a review component, and I would like to build it up as well.

- Short information about the contents to be planned.
- Looking back, building on the existing processes

What else should I look out for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Structure Analysis Documentation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40120/test-structure-analysis-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Your test strategy could have the following items:

1) An overall approach to testing.

2) Types or levels of testing.

3) Tools available/developed at the organization level.

4) Test Entry and Exit criteria.

5) Test Suspension and Resumption criteria.

6) Risks and contingencies.

7) Infra or Test Environment setup

Please note, as per your needs, you can add any relevant and generic item to the strategy. It should act as a guide while creating a Test Plan.

Thanks!